# Show Month on Scorecard for the highest revenue based on Date Range Filtered

Tags: looker-studio

I was thinking of the formula that I should use to show the Month with the highest revenue based on the filtered date range. Below is the sample data on google sheet.

```
Date    Revenue
1/1/2014    $222,080.70
6/1/2014    $227,565.29
7/1/2014    $250,951.29
9/1/2014    $256,936.13
11/1/2014   $248,952.56
12/1/2014   $267,996.00
1/1/2015    $338,808.52
2/1/2015    $284,074.09
```

If the date range will be filtered from January 2014 to December 2014, I want the showcard to present the Month wherein the highest revenue was recorded. In this case, it should show January 2015. Please help me on the right formula I should use in creating field in Google Data Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way it can be achieved is by using a Table and sorting by Revenue (aggregated by Max) in descending order. The headers, pagination, etc can be removed, as well as showing just a single row. This will have the effect of a Scorecard displaying a single date (that's sorted by Max Revenue).

The GIF below goes through the process ([Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7dd98f0d-e3a6-4f2d-b55a-686a1e2b3696)):

[image: 2]]